# Does a given Puppeteer version download the same Chrome version every time?

Tags: google-chrome, npm, puppeteer, mermaid

I have an NPM install where I am installing the [Mermaid CLI](https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid.cli). I want to fix *all* NPM package versions, including Puppeteer, such that they are installed via a `package-lock.json` file.

Now, when Puppeteer installs itself, it downloads a copy of Chrome. A subset of the NPM package versions for Puppeteer are:

```
puppeteer: 19.11.1
puppeteer-core: 19.11.1
puppeteer/browsers: 0.5.0
```

When `npm install` is ran, Puppeteer downloads Chrome to the `.cache` location (which can be set via the `PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR` environment variable) and the version, currently at least, is `<.cache>/chrome/linux-1108766/chrome-linux/chrome`.

---

**The questions are**:

1. Is fixing the NPM Puppeteer package versions enough to ***guarantee*** that Puppeteer will ***always*** download the same 1108766 version of Chrome?
2. If the answer is "no", then is there a way to fix the Chrome version that Puppeteer installs?